# Duplicate Insertion into database

Tags: c#

I'm currently experiencing a funny issue here, each time I insert a new item with EntityFramework, I get to see a new Item submitted first before the real time but with the same entries(properties) and a String[] Array in the last column. I actually have a model defined thus

```
public class SupervisionStageSetupModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StageLevel { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

         public IList<SupervisionStageSetupChecklistModel> SupervisionStageSetupChecklists { get; set; }
       public string GetAuditDetails(string action)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} SupervisionStageSetup Setup:   {1}", action,Name);
        }
    }

public class SupervisionStageSetupChecklistModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SupervisionStageSetupId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string[] Options { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my service, I have a method that does the insert operation as thus

```
private void ProcessCheckListItems(List<SupervisionStageSetupChecklist> entities,
            IList<SupervisionStageSetupChecklistModel> checkListItems, int stageSetupId)
        {
            var modelIds = checkListItems.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

            var supervisionStageSetupChecklistRepository = _repository.GetRepository<SupervisionStageSetupChecklist>();
            var entitiesToDelete =
                entities.Where(x => !modelIds.Contains(x.Id));
            entitiesToDelete.ForEach(x => supervisionStageSetupChecklistRepository.Delete(x));

            var entitiesToAdd = checkListItems.Where(x => x.Id == 0).Select(x =>
                new SupervisionStageSetupChecklist()
                {
                    Description = x.Description,
                    SupervisionStageSetupId = stageSetupId,
                    Options = String.Join(",",x.Options)
                }).ToList();
            entitiesToAdd.ForEach(x =>
            {
                supervisionStageSetupChecklistRepository.Insert(x);
            }

                );
            var entityToUpdate =
                entities.Where(x => modelIds.Contains(x.Id));
            entityToUpdate.ForEach(source =>
            {

                var checklistItem = checkListItems.Single(x => x.Id == source.Id);

                source.Description = checklistItem.Description;
                source.Options = String.Join(",",checklistItem.Options);
                supervisionStageSetupChecklistRepository.Update(source);
            });
```

When I put my VS2013 in debug mode to see what's happening, I saw that it was just only the number of items that came from the view that was inserted, but going back to my MSSQL2014 , I found two records inserted as

```
Id| SupervisionStageId | Description | Options
2 | 3                  | Description | String[] Array   
3 | 3                  | Description | Yes,No
```

And of course, after setting breakpoint while inserting, I hovered on the entitiesToAdd object which returned 1 as the count, and this not enough, retrieving the item with the following ...

```
public SupervisionStageSetupItem GetDetails(int id)
        {
var entity = _repository.Find(id);
            var item = Mapper.Map<SupervisionStageSetup, SupervisionStageSetupItem>(entity);
            item.SupervisionStageSetupChecklists =
                entity.SupervisionStageSetupChecklists.Where(x => x.SupervisionStageSetupId == entity.Id)
                    .Select(x => new SupervisionStageSetupChecklistModel()
                    {
                        Description = x.Description,Options = x.Options.Split(',')
                    }).ToList();
            return item;
}
```

I got the one Options property value as "Y","e","s",",","N","o".

I'm perplexed!, Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Where is tha angularjs relevant code? Or you do tag by random association?

Comment: You mean for the view?

Comment: He means we are seeing this question pop up in AngularJS's newest questions while as the question stands right now it has no relation to AngularJS.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm also using Angularjs for my views, that's why I included it in the tag session

Comment: I don't think you have to apologize. You added the tag in your best intent, even though it was wrong and not related. But I don't think that is a excuse for being rude with people. This severely demotivate people from posting here. He could requested an edit and you could accept.